# Automatically missing underline when typing SQL query

Tags: vb.net, ide, visual-studio-2015, underline

I'm quite new to vb. I've made some queries in vb.net. When I type next line query, the underline symbol automatically missing. Anyone who knows what went wrong? Is there any dependency or some other reason? Thanks for helping.

```
 SQLStr = "INSERT INTO tblUserAccess " & _  '<---- this underline missing automatically
         " (UserLogin, AccessID) " & _  '<----this one also
         " VALUES (" & _  '<---- this
         SQLS(strLoginID) & "," & _ <---this
         SQLS(intOrderRequest) & "); SELECT scope_identity()"
```

Comment: It is no longer required to type this. I'm guessing your on VS15? It might be an auto-enforced formatting rule MS added.

Comment: yup. im using VS15. is that the only reason why is that happen?

Comment: since u have asked quetion related to IDE,you should also tag using the same.

Comment: i dont even know that its related to IDE. but the things got more confusing. some of the query automatically remove the "_" symbol. some are not. what is happening here?

Comment: I can confirm that this behaviour occurs on my install as well (VS15). It can be disabled by disabling "pretty listing" in the settings but obviously disabling this setting disables a lot more that just automatic underscore removal in multiline strings.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Basic -> Advance -> Uncheck the Code arrange format of Editor description

> VS 2019 Taiwan's edition

[image]